# Microsoft Word is displaying weird symbols when pressing enter

Tags: interaction-design

I was writing a text for my thesis and everything was going good.

Suddenly, as i was writing, i pressed something (don't know what it was) and i started getting weird symbols when i pressed neter or shift enter.

The characters look like this:

[image]

I don't know what to do since deadline is approaching.

I have tried pushing every possible combination that i could have pressed by accident, yet 
everything remains the same

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about troubleshooting a desktop application and not user experience.

Comment: You put Word into Outline Mode: http://cybersavvyservices.wordpress.com/2011/04/22/word-outline-mode/ - in the future, please consider asking questions like this on the SuperUser board. http://superuser.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for UX.SE but is perfectly suited on [SuperUser.SE](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the symbol representing a paragraph - which is what you do when pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. You use this mode to see what formatting you have in a word document do make a flawless formatted word document.

You can deselect this using the button with the same symbol in the ribbon, like this:

[image]

Comment: The [pilcrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow) symbol does not represent a line break, it represents a paragraph.  A new line symbol is [different](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22128/what-font-and-characters-are-used-for-the-line-break-symbol-used-in-microsoft)

Answer (score 2):

Look in the Home tab in the Paragraph tools. The same paragraph symbol should be there, just click on it to deactivate it.  These symbols indicate a new paragraph on screen but not in print.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there something incorrect in this answer?  I decided not to insert pretty pictures because the user should be able to search with a little help, not by giving him/her an explicit roadmap.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to even up the score, since your answer is correct. I hate it when users downvote without a comment on why. That's why we should always [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)

Comment: I didn't downvote but simply being correct here is a not of much help. Anyone not familiar with ribbon menus is lost without pictures. It is for this reason alone that I prefer @BennySkogberg's answer.

Comment: Thanks for your input (and I agree that @BennySkogberg's answer is better), but if this is so then in the answer should be included screen captures for almost all versions of Word.  The interface is not exactly the same throughout all of them, but the general location of the pilcrow and paragraph tools is the same in all of them.